# "call to 'triangle' is ambiguous" error

Tags: c++, xcode, recursion

```
#include "rec_fun.h"
using namespace mry2270;

void triangle(ostream& outs, unsigned int m, unsigned int n){
    if (m <= n){
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout<< endl;
        triangle(outs, ++m, n);
    }
    else if (m > n && n >= 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout<< endl;
        triangle(outs, m, --n);
    }
}

void numbers(ostream& outs, const string& prefix, unsigned int levels){

}

bool bears(int n){
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {



    return 0;
}

#ifndef rec_fun_h
#define rec_fun_h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//  void triangle(ostream& outs, unsigned int m, unsigned int n)
// Precondition: m <= n
// Postcondition: The function has printed a pattern of 2*(n-m+1) lines
// to the output stream outs. The first line contains m asterisks, the next
// line contains m+1 asterisks, and so on up to a line with n asterisks.
// Then the pattern is repeated backwards, going n back down to m.
/* Example output:
 triangle(cout, 3, 5) will print this to cout:
 ***
 ****
 *****
 *****
 ****
 ***
 */
//
//  bool bears(int n)
// Postcondition: A true return value means that it is possible to win
// the bear game by starting with n bears. A false return value means that
// it is not possible to win the bear game by starting with n bears.
// Examples:
//   bear(250) is true (as shown above)
//   bear(42) is true
//   bear(84) is true
//   bear(53) is false
//   bear(41) is false
//
//  bool bears(int n)
// Postcondition: A true return value means that it is possible to win
// the bear game by starting with n bears. A false return value means that
// it is not possible to win the bear game by starting with n bears.
// Examples:
//   bear(250) is true (as shown above)
//   bear(42) is true
//   bear(84) is true
//   bear(53) is false
//   bear(41) is false

namespace mry2270 {

    void triangle(ostream& outs, unsigned int m, unsigned int n);

    void numbers(ostream& outs, const string& prefix, unsigned int levels);

    bool bears(int n);

}
```

I'm working on a recursion class and keep getting this error. Any idea how to fix it?

Edit: this is the main.cpp file

I think the underlying problem might be under the .h file, but I'm not sure.

Edit: I have added the .h file and have updated my parameter in the recursion call. I am still getting "call to 'triangle' is ambiguous" error and am now getting a "Comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true" error.

Comment: With Respect, this looks like an assignment on Recursion and if you fast-forward this lesson using Stack Overflow, you'll suffer later in Programming.

Comment: My implementation is correct, but it's my syntax that I need some help with.

Comment: For this error to appear, there must be another declaration of a function named `triangle`, with different parameter types. The problem lies in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: There are many problems with the given code that will prevent compilation (I suspect rec_fun.h contains `using namespace std;`. I recommend not placing `using namespace std;` in a header and avoiding it in general) but nothing that should cause ambiguity. Can we see what is in rec_fun.h

Comment: moving the "using namespace std;" to my .cpp file fixed my ambiguous error, but I am now stuck with a "Comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true" error.

Comment: Can you give the exact line  where the warning `Comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true` occrus ?

Comment: its occurring on "    else if (m > n && n >= 0) "

Comment: `n` is an `unsigned int`. It is impossible for `n` to be negative, so `n >= 0` must be true.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem, but you probably don't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the header, there is a forward declaration

```
namespace mry2270 {
    void triangle(ostream& outs, unsigned int m, unsigned int n);
    ...
}
```

promising that a function `mry2270::triangle` exists somewhere.

The cpp file defines a function named `triangle`.

```
void triangle(ostream& outs, int m, int n){
```

Note the difference in the names. `triangle` is not `mry2270::triangle`, breaking the promise made by the header. Normally this would be caught by the linker when it went looking for the implementation of `mry2270::triangle`.

Where things get weird is `using namespace mry2270;` allows `mry2270::triangle`  to be referred to as `triangle`. There is already a `triangle`, resulting in ambiguity reported by the compiler.

The can be resolved by adding the namespace to the implementation of `triangle`. Replace

```
void triangle(ostream& outs, unsigned int m, unsigned int n) {
```

with

```
void mry2270::triangle(ostream& outs, unsigned int m, unsigned int n) {
```

With that sorted out, you can move on to sorting out the remaining errors that other answers have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this code to trigger the error that you mention there must be a separate declaration of `triangle` that conflicts with the definition you provided in the code - for example, a forward declaration with different parameter types.

The real problem with your code is that it causes stack overflow. Look carefully at this invocation:

```
triangle(outs, m++, n);
```

Do you see why the call passes `triangle` the same exact values of `m` and `n`? If you said "post-increment," you get a gold star for your answer: the call should use `m+1` to fix this problem; similarly, `n--` in the other invocation should be changed to `n-1`.

Additionally, there is no path in your code to exit the recursion, because both branches end up calling `triangle` unconditionally. You should add a check for `n` to be zero, and add a return if it is about to go negative after subtraction (of course, it cannot go negative because it is `unsigned`, but your program would print lots of unwanted asterisks once `n` overflows).

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/ttsQMB)

Answer (score 0):

> **call to 'triangle' is ambiguous** error

No, your `triangle` is not ambiguous, at least from your example.

Your `triangle`, however, has its own (two) problems - there's no termination to stop the recursion, and a wrong usage of `operator++` and `operator--` as follows:

```
void triangle(ostream& outs, int m, int n){
    if (m <= n){
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout<< endl;
        triangle(outs, ++m, n); // instead of triangle(outs, m++, n);
    } 
    else if (m > n && n >= 0) { // if `n` is negative, exits.
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout<< endl;
        triangle(outs, m, --n); // instead of triangle(outs, m, n--)
    }
}
```